# Give Chai/Mocha a partial list of keys that should be included

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

It seems that if I do

```
describe( 'Add Youtube', function () {

    it( 'should return the video data, including user, title and content fields', function ( done ) {

        this.timeout( 5000 )

        request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost:8443/api/add',
            json: true,
            strictSSL: false,
            body: {
                "type": "youtube",
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxfRLNiSikM"
            },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + newTestUser.token
            } }, function ( err, response, body ) {

                body.should.include.keys( [ "user", "title", "content" ] )

                done()
        })
    })
})
```

That this will return an error since the object coming back also has the key `message`. How can I have this come back as passed as long as the 3 keys in the array are present, despite any more being there. I can't always predict what's going to be there in each case.

---

UPDATE: Here is how I'm requiring Chai and `should`.

```
var chai = require( 'chai' ),
    chaiAsPromised = require( 'chai-as-promised' ),
    should = require( 'chai' ).should(),
    path = require( 'path' ),
    getUser = require( '../helpers/get-user' ),
    userController = require( '../controllers/userController' ),
    blogController = require( '../controllers/blogController' ),
    request = require( 'request' ),
    User = require( '../models/userModel' ),
    Content = require( '../models/contentModel' ),
    shortid = require( 'shortid' )

chai.use( chaiAsPromised )
```

Comment: Not sure if it works, but what if you add the `all` property like `body.should.include.all.keys( [ "user", "title", "content" ] )`

Comment: One thing to note is that `chai.should()` modifies Object.prototype by adding its own function as `Object.prototype.should`. While violates accepted 'best practice', it is usually accepted since the value of extending the Object prototype in this way outweighs any possible issues. The only instance where this can bite you is if you have an object that also defined its own prototypal `should()`, in which case, testing will fail. Just a word to the wise. ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you have an object like this one (similar to what you described):

```
var obj= {
  user: "user",
  title: "title",
  content: "content",
  message: "message"
};
```

all the following assertions should pass:

```
obj.should.include.keys(["user", "title", "content"]);
obj.should.includes.keys(["user", "title", "content"]);
obj.should.contain.keys(["user", "title", "content"]);
obj.should.includes.keys(["user", "title", "content"]);
```

even if you pass the values as separated arguments:

```
obj.should.include.keys("user", "title", "content");
obj.should.includes.keys("user", "title", "content");
obj.should.contain.keys("user", "title", "content");
obj.should.includes.keys("user", "title", "content");
```

So, assuming that you required `chai`'s `should` style correctly:

```
var should = require('chai').should();
```

, your problem may be just a typo in your `body` object or in your test suite.

**UPDATE:** After you added more information about the way you required all testing modules, a couple things should be pointed out:

- First, you required `chai` two times, the second one when setting up `should`. You did:

  ```
  var chai = require( 'chai' ),
      should = require( 'chai' ).should(),
      ...
  ```

  when you should've done:

  ```
  var chai = require( 'chai' ),
      should = chai.should(),
      ...
  ```
- Second, if you're using `chai-as-promised`, you should assert `body` keys [the way this module requires](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/#how-to-use), like:

  ```
  Promise.resolve(body).should.eventually.include.keys([ "user", "title", "content" ]);
  ```

Comment: That's what I expected and how I think I set it up. See my updated post with my `var = should` part.

Comment: For what it's worth, requiring a module more than once simply returned the already cached module from require.cache. This is why trying to re-require a module in the REPL won't reflect any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the simplest solution be, within your request handler, to:

```
function ( err, response, body ) {
  var expected={},
      expected_keys=['user','title','content'];

  expected_keys.forEach(function(key){
    expected[key]=body[key];
  });

  expected.should.include.keys(expected_keys);

  done();
}
```

Or using one of my fav tools, [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#pick):

```
var _=require('lodash');

function ( err, response, body ) {
  var expected_keys=['user','title','content'];

  _.pick(body,expected_keys).should.include.keys(expected_keys);

  done();
}
```